# SwiftUI: List cell height to follow height of contained view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
struct TestContainer: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            
            GeometryReader { geo in
                let _ = print("geo.size.width: \(geo.size.width)")
            
                ZStack {
                    
                    Color.white
                    
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: geo.size.width)
                
            }
                
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I want the "cell" to show up as a square in the list. Right now it shows up like this:

[image]

If I comment out the `List` the view shows up as a square.

How can I make the cell follow the `height` of the content in it?

Comment: Why not geo.size.height instead of geo.size.width since the height is more restricted than the width?

Comment: This approach really isn't going to work, but I think you are thinking about this incorrectly. A `List` is a greedy view in that it tries to take up the available space, so the width of each list row is always going to be the width available to the `List`. So, the only way to change the width of a row is to limit the width available to the `List`. What, exactly, is in the view that you are using as a cell for the row? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I removed the width maxFrame modifier to avoid confusion of what I am trying to achieve. The width is not the problem. The problem is the list row is clipping the height I want the row to have. I am not sure yet but I think having geometry reader inside the cell is throwing things off.